# How to Implement SRCAND with Java?

Tags: java, graphics, jframe, bitblt

If I want to use Java to implement the `SRCAND` effect of `BitBlt()` in VC++, that is, perform `AND` operation on the image and background. For the following example, how can I mix the red string `AAAAAAAA` in the background with the corresponding part of the image `m_image`?

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class t_srcand {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new t_srcand();
    }

    public t_srcand() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test SRCAND");

        frame.add(new mypanel());
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class mypanel extends JPanel {
        private BufferedImage m_image;

        public mypanel() {
            try {
                m_image = ImageIO.read(new File("image.jpg"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(Color.red);
            g2d.drawString("AAAAAAAA", 0, 20);

            if (m_image != null) {
                g2d.drawImage(m_image, 0, 0, 300, 200, this);
            }

            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

If `m_image` is a completely opaque image, when it is drawn on the surface of a red string, it will overwrite the red string. So is it possible to obtain the pixel array of the area covered by the m_image before drawing it?

Comment: Simplest to use an image format that supports transparency such as PNG. Could be a prerequisite but not totally sure